# Precise mathematical relation between chirality (or $\gamma_5$) and (spatial) orientation in $1+3$ Minkowski spacetime

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, orientation

This is a bit of a qualitative question, but I have great difficulty finding a reference that clarifies the point I have been confused about. So, I guess I need to ask here..

Let us restrict atttetion to $1+3$ Minkowski spacetime. I am aware that dimension $4$ is the lowest one in which Clifford algebra has a representation in terms of gamma matrices $\gamma_0, \cdots, \gamma_3$.

Then, $\gamma_5$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\gamma_5 := i \gamma_0 \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_2
\end{equation}
and is associated with so-called "chirality" as in  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices). In particular, the terminology "left-handed / right-handed" Dirac fields appear.

Also, [wiki-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)) introduces the notion of orientation, especially in 3D Euclidean space. Again the phrases "left / right -handed$ are defined as two choies of orientations related to each other by reflection.

My question : How do the left / right-handedness for the Dirac fields correspond to two choices of orientation in the 3D Euclidean space. Could anyone please clarify for me in a mathematically rigorous manner?

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

Chirality is related to orientation via spin-momentum locking.

The projector $P_\pm=\tfrac{1}{2}(1\pm\gamma_5)$ projects a spinor onto two subspaces that are decoupled in the evolution equation of a massless fermion ($\gamma_5$ commutes with the Dirac Hamiltonian if the mass term vanishes). The chiral subspaces are eigenspaces of the socalled [helicity operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics)), which projects the spin onto the momentum. So a massless fermion has both a definite chirality (its spinor is an eigenstate of $P_+$ or $P_-$) and a definite helicity: its spin is oriented parallel or antiparallel to the momentum. One speaks of a right-handed or left-handed orientation, with reference to the [right-hand-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) in 3D space.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So, the two eigenspaces of the helicity operator correspond to the two choices of orientation? Is this correspondence some kind of "isomorphism"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "definite" chirality for masssless fermions? Physically, chirality of massive fermion depends on the frame of reference while that of massless fermion does not. How is this physics formulated in the language of mathematics?

Comment: "definite" chirality of a massless fermion means that the two subspaces onto which $P_\pm$ projects are not coupled by the equations of motion; the term that couples the subspaces is called a "mass term", which is why one cannot assign a chirality to a massive fermion.